# How to add cummulatively associative arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I add cummalatively this array below :

```
array
  Product 1 => 
   array 
     0 => float 8065.45
  Product 2 => 
    array 
      0 => float 8065.45


array
  Product 1 => 
   array 
     0 => float 8065.45
   array 
     0 => float 158.65
  Product 2 => 
    array 
      0 => float 8065.45
    array 
      0 => float 11736.37
```

I am currently using `array_sum` for this but I think its not working.

Comment: what have you try?

Comment: first of all make a proper array your second array will be overridden, and show your code what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

use foreach and array_sum to sum it.

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($products as $product)
{
  foreach($product as $v)
  {
    $sum += array_sum($v);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By "adding cummulatively", I think you mean **appending**.

So, giving you example:

```php
<?php

$products = [
    'Product 1' => [8065.45],
    'Product 2' => [8065.45]
];

var_dump($products);

$products['Product 1'][] = 158.65;
$products['Product 2'][] = 11736.37;

var_dump($products);
```

It should returns:

```
array(2) {
    ["Product 1"] => array(1) {
        [0]=> float(8065.45)
    }
    ["Product 2"] => array(1) {
        [0]=> float(8065.45)
    }
}

array(2) {
    ["Product 1"] => array(2) {
        [0]=> float(8065.45)
        [1]=> float(158.65)
    }
    ["Product 2"] => array(2) {
        [0]=> float(8065.45)
        [1]=> float(11736.37)
    }
}
```

You can also use the [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) function.